# How to convert VMDK to VDI/VHD

Tags: virtualbox

[It's said](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-modifyvdi) that VirtualBox's `VBoxManage modifyhd --resize` command can only be used on either VDI or VHD files. Sadly, I have a VirtualBox image that is in VMDK format, and I don't know how to convert it to those other two formats.

Comment: Is `clonehd` not an option for you?

Comment: If it converts to VDI, it is.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use a two-step procedure then - first, use the `clonemedium` command to create a VDI image:

```
VBoxManage clonemedium disk aaaa.vmdk aaaa.vdi --format VDI
```

(Have a look also at other options to `clonemedium`, like `--variant`. To read the help, just run `VBoxManage | less` or visit https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-clonevdi).

Once you have the `.vdi` file, you can proceed with your modifications.

Comment: This even works if the VMDK file points to (parts of) a [raw disk image](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#rawdisk) (as created by `VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk`).

Answer (score 6):

If you would like to convert only the virtual disk, not entire VM, you can also use qemu-img for Windows: it's free, portable and it runs under command prompt.

VirtualBox, VMware, Hyper-V disk image types are all supported.

For example, to convert VMDK to VHDX:

```
qemu-img.exe convert FileSource-Image.vmdk -O vhdx FileDestination-Image.vhdx
```

Extracted from: http://www.sysadmit.com/2016/08/vmware-convertir-vhdx-en-vmdk.html

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed. QEMU is great since it is installable cross-platform too.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert .vmdk files into .vdi and .vhd files in VirtualBox7 using the GUI in the following way:

- in the VirtualBox GUI under "Copy Medium" select the file to be converted.
- and then select .vdi or .vhd as the target format.
- and then execute the conversion